# How to detect When the firestore's data changed

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(
          'AMB/' + "$_args['car']" + "$_args['name']" + "/message")
      .snapshots(),
  builder: ((BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
    print(snapshot.connectionState);
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Container();
    }
    final docs = snapshot.data!.docChanges;
    if(docs.length != 0)
    {
      displayToast("AMB DB CHANGED!", false);
      print(docs);
      // change tab
    }
    return SizedBox();
  }),
),
```

I'm trying to make tab changes when the Firestore's data changed.

so I just build my StreamBuilder() in AppBar().
and this thing does not reacts when I change my datas.
(they only send connectionstate only 2~3 times)

What should I do to solve this problem?